# Three.js fireball example and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, three.js

Alterdq's Fireball example at http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_shader_fireball.html is a great example of using procedural noise generation in a shader. I've used it as a basis for some other shaders I've been writing in Three.js, but I noticed none of them work in IE. So I tried Alterdq's Fireball in IE 11 and I see the same error: the shader is apparently too complex? What are the limits being exceeded in IE 11's WebGL implementation? (FWIW: the Fireball shader & my derivatives work fine on Firefox & Chrome in Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback! The April update to IE11’s WebGL implementation increased the shader complexity limit to enable more real-world content to run. The URL you linked to works with an up-to-date IE11.

Disclosure: I am on the team that worked on Microsoft's implementation of WebGL.